# pyral Error "pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: SSL certificate verification failed"

Tags: python, rally, pyral

Attempting to access rally1.rallydev.com through the Web Services API v2.0 with pyral 1.1.1 and ActivePython 2.7.10.12 (ActiveState Software Inc.) from behind a corporate file wall.  I receive the error “pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: SSL certificate verification failed”

```
Using Code with ssl: 

    rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project)

Receive:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\QvaleL\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Extract Rally Data\PullRallyUS - Working.py", line 26, in <module>
    rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyral\restapi.py", line 228, in __init__
    self.contextHelper.check(self.server)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyral\context.py", line 216, in check
    raise RallyRESTAPIError(problem)
pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: SSL certificate verification failed



Using Code to turn off SSL:

 rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project, verify_ssl_cert=False)

Receive:

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:791: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
404 Response for request
('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\QvaleL\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Extract Rally Data\PullRallyUS - Working.py", line 25, in <module>
    rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project, verify_ssl_cert=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyral\restapi.py", line 228, in __init__
    self.contextHelper.check(self.server)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyral\context.py", line 216, in check
    raise RallyRESTAPIError(problem)
pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: 404 Target host: 'rally1.rallydev.com' doesn't support the Rally WSAPI
```

installed Python Packages

```
c:\>pip list
   certifi (2016.2.28)
   pip (8.1.1)
   pypm (1.4.3)
   pyral (1.1.1)
   pythonselect (1.3)
   pywin32 (218.3)
   requests (2.9.1)
   setuptools (5.2)
   virtualenv (1.11.6)
```

Comment: Hey @Les. You're more likely to get an answer if you write your post as a clear, answerable question. Right now, this is an error report: the reader doesn't know what you want help with, what you need to achieve, nor why the error is a problem. The reader also don't know what you've done to investigate the problem nor resolve the issue on your own. With a little editing you should hopefully see some good responses to what looks like a tricky issue. :)

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to export the environment variable https_proxy=[your https proxy-server_IP:port] within your environment or through the Python program. To export from within the Python program use the following command syntax with [your https proxy-server_IP:port]:

```
os.environ['https_proxy'] = '100.100.101.200:8080'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, our Network team had cleared few checks for the Rally site and it worked. The have cleared SSL verification.

This might not help you but this is how I resolved it, as no other solutions worked for me.